# Keystone multiple languages

Tags: keystonejs

I'm making a keystone project and I want to add different languages. Is it possible to do it from the AdminUI? Can I make a different structure for the different languages? For example:
`ENG
 - home
 - news
   * news1
   * news2
- menu item random
EST
 - home
 - events
    *event1
    *event2
 - news for locals
 - etc`
Thanks in advance!